# TableViewのセルの内容を再描画したくない

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

`TableView`をスクロールするとレイアウトがぐちゃぐちゃになってしまい、調べた結果それはセルの再描画によるものらしいので`TableView`をスクロールしてもセルを再描画したくないのですが、どうすればよろしいでしょうか？
ちなみに

```
for (UIView *subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

としても各セルの内容が全て消えてしまいうまくいきませんでした。
セルの数もあまりないので、とりあえず今の段階では再描画させない方法が知りたいです。
各セルにはカスタムセルを使っています。
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: それは無理です。テーブルそのものを止める以外ありません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。セルを再描画させない方法はないのですね。了解しました。他の方法を探してみたいと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**セルの再描画は止められない**ことについて、説明します。まずは、検証用のサンプルコードです。

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController {
    int cellNumber;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    cellNumber = 1;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 100;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.tag == 0) {
        cell.tag = cellNumber++;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Cell's tag = %ld", cell.tag];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

なにをやっているコードかというと、セルが初めて生成されたときに、プロパティtagに連番で整数値を代入し、textLabelにtagの値を表示するというものです。
シミュレータで実行したとき、テーブルビューに表示される行数は、15行でしたが、tagの番号は17までで止まり、スクロールすると、1〜17までの番号がくり返し出てくるだけという結果になりました。なお、総行数は100に設定してあります。
これは、表示行数に2足した数だけのセルが作られ、スクロールすると、枠から出て行ったセルが、つぎつぎ再利用されてまた現れるというメカニズムを、視覚化しています。
セルが枠から出て行ったら、すぐに「再描画」される、というのが実態であることが、わかっていただけると思います。

正攻法でいきましょうよ。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。セルの再描画は必ずされるものなのですね。検証サンプルで分かりました。正攻法でいきたいと思います。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

UITableViewにはリサイクル機構があり、`tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`で`addSubView`などをしていると表示が崩れる場合があります。表示数が少ないのであれば、リサイクルさせない様にする方法はどうでしょう。(その都度、生成させるようにする方法です。)

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%d",indexPath.row]
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
}
```

`Identifier`をバラバラにすることで、`row`の数分生成されるはずです。
数が多い場合は、重くなるので素直に`UITableView`のサブクラスを作る事をオススメします。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。現在カスタムセルを使っており、reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier で以下のようにそれぞれのカスタムセルを指定しています。static const id identifiers[5] = {@"normalCell", @"cell", @"detailCell", @"halfCell", @"normalCell"};
    NSString *CellIdentifier = identifiers[indexPath.row];
この場合ご提示いただいたようにIdentifierをバラバラにするにはどうすればよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: @kojianu カスタムセルを利用されているのであれば、`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`を使い、識別子(CellIdentifier)でcell取得し、ぞれぞれにあわせて設定をしていけば崩れることはないはずなのですが.....

Comment: カスタムセルとStoryboardの紐付け方に問題があったようです。カスタムセルとStoryboardをきちんと紐付け、dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifierでセルを設定すると、セルの表示が崩れることがなくなりました。